# A specific URL causes axios nuxt module to not run callback

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

So I have setup two buttons called "Confirm" and "Delete" on my nuxt.js page. Each button, when clicked, will run confirm() and delete() respectively. The code for the two functions are nearly identical, the only difference being that the URLs are different. When running delete(), it performs a GET request with axios and the callback is run perfectly and does what I want it to do. However, when running confirm(), it performs the request but the callback isn't run.

I thought maybe the API server isn't responding. However, when I checked the logs, the response is actually being sent.

```
1zcu ——> GET /api/pending/delete/5d554a5d9ddb8079158eefcc 
1zcu <—— 200 OK 15 B application/json; charset=utf-8 (<—> 326.1 ms)
yefy ——> GET /api/pending/confirm/5d554a5c9ddb8079158eefcb 
yefy <—— 200 OK 14 B application/json; charset=utf-8 (<—> 540.9 ms)
```

So I tried changing the URL in the confirm() function to match the one in the delete() function and sure enough, it started working.

Functions

```
    confirm(id) {
      this.setConfirming(id);

      const url = CON_URL + id;
      this.$axios.$get(url).then((res) => {
        if (!res.error) {
          console.log(res)
          this.refresh();
        }
      });
    },
    discard(id) {
      this.setDeleting(id);

      const url = DEL_URL + id;
      this.$axios.$get(url).then((res) => {
        if (!res.error) {
          console.log(res)
          this.refresh();
        }
      });
    },
```

URLs

```
const DEL_URL = "/api/pending/delete/";
const CON_URL = "/api/pending/confirm/";
```

Buttons

```
<td v-if="!enquiry.isConfirming"><button v-on:click="confirm(enquiry._id)" class="button is-primary">Confirm</button></td>
<td v-if="!enquiry.isDeleting"><button v-on:click="discard(enquiry._id)" class="button is-danger">Discard</button></td>
```

Express endpoints

```
router.get('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    Pending.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, pending) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ error: true });
        } else {
            res.json({ error: false });
        }
    });
});

router.get('/confirm/:id', (req, res) => {
    Pending.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, pending) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ error: true });
        } else {
            const confirmed = new Booking(pending);
            confirmed.save((err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({ error: true });
                } else {
                    res.json({ error: false });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.then` is only executed if the task completed without exception. You may also need to attach a callback for the error condition with `Promise.catch`:

```
this.$axios.$get(url)
    .then((res) => {
        console.info(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        console.info('done');
    });
```

Comment: I fixed it with a different solution but it causes me to have a new question, could you help me? I posted an answer in this question.

Comment: Ok nevermind, it still isn't working. It was working because I changed CON_URL to match DEL_URL. I'll try your solution.

Comment: I tried your solution... it isn't catching any err nor is it running the .then() callback.